# Spring ParamsInterceptor complains about @RequestParam- BEFORE REQUEST

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, get-request

i'am sending ajax get request to spring mvc handler and i can pass parameter-values.
Problem is, that i became ERROR everytime:

> spring.interceptor.ParamsInterceptor - BEFORE REQUEST:
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'fromDate' of bean class
>   [com.example.CallDbController]: Bean
>   property 'fromDate' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
>   Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the
>   getter?
>   [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

My Ajax-Requst:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'myUrl.action',
        data : {
            "fromDate" : start
        },
        success : function(msg) {
            console.log('something to do...');
        }
    });
```

and my controller handler:

```
  @Controller
@RequestMapping("/calldb/*")
public class CallDbController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "myUrl.action" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String[] getTimeDifference(@RequestParam("fromDate") String startDate) {
                                                    //something to do...
                                                    }
}
```

I'am confusing, that "fromDate" Request-Parameter from GET-Request 
is being interprited as Bean-Property.

Answer (score 0):

i've finde my problem. Exception has been thrown due to Implementation of some interceptor.